# is still running you can attach to it by selecting debug and app is crash when download images

Tags: ios, image, download

In ios I am downloading 17 images and showing in a collection view, images are too big and after 5 to 6 images app is crashing and Xcode is showing this error **"is still running you can attach to it by selecting Debug"** I am using **WebCache** library to download image and showing in collection view, when I changed URL (using small image then is working properly) but not working with big images image is may be 1 to 1.50 MB some image is 6000 x 4000 and some images are 3000 x 4000 , here is  my code please give me solution what should i do . may be some limitation to download image in ios

```
 NSURL *url_of_image = [NSURL URLWithString:getUrll];
    [myCell.img setImageWithURL:url_of_image usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this with **AFNetworking** [setImageWithURL:]? It works great with async downloading of big images too .